# Control and F equivalent in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an equivalent of the human control and f function for VBA?

Basically I have two very long sheets which have some values in common but some unique values and I'm trying to merge them into one.

The simple code way of doing this is through two nested loops- run through list B until you find the matching list A, then move to the next entry of list A and run all the way through list B again.

It is horribly inefficient.

Is there any simple way to tell the code to just quickly find the bit of data from this cell on the other sheet and then match those rows?

Comment: Have you tried recording the CTRL+F function in Excel yet?

Comment: it needs to be automated. I'm not merging hundreds of piece of data manually ;)

Comment: Why do you say it is inefficient? Maybe you just coded it in an inefficient way? Without more concrete info, we can't help.

Comment: recursivly going through every single row just to find something that you can find in a second doing it manually is super inefficient. Nested row=row+1 loops are very newbie style. I think the info is quite concrete. What more is there to say?

Comment: @theotherone, you can record a macro while pressing the CTRL+F function in Excel. Then open the editor and you'll have the code for the CTRL+F function. Then you just switch around your search value with a variable.

Comment: that could work...but then how would I retrieve the found cell's row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a human, you would loop through sheet one, copy the first cell, switch to the 2nd sheet, then <kbd>Ctrol</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to find the text, perform your action based on whether or not you found it, then return to sheet 1. Lather, rinse, repeat.

That's exactly what your code should be doing. Use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range().Find` instead of <kbd>Ctrol</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

If you had followed CustomX's suggestion of recording a macro to do this, that's what you would have found.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsofts help file on the FIND method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Also my answer to this post might point you in the right direction:
[Loop through sheet, look for specific value, paste row with matching value to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137636/vba-loop-through-sheet-look-for-specific-value-paste-row-with-matching-value/29151218#29151218)

And I definitely agree:

> The simple code way of doing this is through two nested loops- run
>   through list B until you find the matching list A, then move to the
>   next entry of list A and run all the way through list B again.

That's a very inefficient way of doing it.